# SQL Try Catch for specific severity only

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, try-catch

Hi I have a long SQL script which runs as a single transaction to bulk import from files.

When running the script I am finding that I get some informational messages, some warnings and then some errors that immediately halt the running of the script - however it doesn't rollback the transaction.

To get around this I used a try-catch block which now successfully rolls back the transaction if there are any errors; however my info and warnings also trigger the catch block and stop my script when it needent have done.

Is there a way to only jump to the catch for critical errors, for the warnings and info messages I simply want to test @@error and insert it to a string then output these all to the user at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using RaiseError event?

severity level 0-9 should be used for informational level messages.

For more information

[RaiseError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

[Database Engine Severity Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,I hope it will give you solution

string cnnString =WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cnnString);
    SqlTransaction transaction;

```
cnn.Open();
transaction = cnn.BeginTransaction();

try
{

    // Command Objects for the transaction
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("sproc1", cnn);
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("sproc2", cnn);

    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Param1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50));
    cmd1.Parameters["@Param1"].Value = paramValue1;

    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Param2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50));
    cmd1.Parameters["@Param2"].Value = paramValue2;

    cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Param3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50));
    cmd2.Parameters["@Param3"].Value = paramValue3;

    cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Param4", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50));
    cmd2.Parameters["@Param4"].Value = paramValue4;
```

cmd2.Parameters.Add("@out", OleDbType.NVarCha);
    myCommand.Parameters["@out"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

```
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    transaction.Commit();
}

 catch (SqlException sqlExc)
      {
          foreach (SqlError error in sqlExc.Errors)
          {
             string errors = string.Format("{0}: ", error.Message);
              cmd2.Parameters["@out"].Value) = errors;
```

transaction.Rollback();

```
          }
      }

finally
{
    cnn.Close();
    cnn.Dispose();
}
```